# Openshift app url shows "Welcome to you application" after deploy

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I'm new to Openshift so excuse me plz.
I've created an app there, filled it with cartridges and pushed a wordpress app. Deploy was successfull:

```
Compressing objects: 100% (1547/1547), done.

Writing objects: 100% (1585/1585), 8.45 MiB | 1.09 MiB/s, done.

Total 1585 (delta 171), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: Stopping MySQL cartridge

remote: Stopping PHP cartridge

remote: [Mon Jan 20 11:06:14 2014] [warn] PassEnv variable SHELL was undefined

remote: [Mon Jan 20 11:06:14 2014] [warn] PassEnv variable USER was undefined

remote: [Mon Jan 20 11:06:14 2014] [warn] PassEnv variable LOGNAME was undefined

remote: Waiting for stop to finish

remote: Waiting for stop to finish

remote: Building git ref 'master', commit bb4ea05

remote: Building PHP cartridge

remote: Preparing build for deployment

remote: Deployment id is a59ab2e6

remote: Activating deployment

remote: Starting MySQL cartridge

remote: Starting PHP cartridge

remote: Result: success

remote: Activation status: success

remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

And rhc also shows deploy was ok:

```
Deployment ID c60001d7 (active)
-------------------------------
  Git Reference:     master

  SHA1:              1ac8629

  Created At:        8:14 PM

  Hot Deploy:        false

  Force Clean Build: false

  Activations:       8:16 PM
```

But yet url of the application leads to an **"Welcome to your PHP application on OpenShift"** page... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your wordpress application into the php directory of your cloned repository?  Also make sure that you replaced the index.php file.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a lot - I didn't notice the php folder!